# How to retrieve access token from Reddit via OAuth flow with Java

Tags: java, oauth, reddit

I have my authorisation url - https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=xuJKekGTr1-V8Q&response_type=code&state=dfDfsd4gdf&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/redditimageuploader/callback&duration=permanent&scope=submit

But I don't really know what to do from here? I've found a few guides online but it's just a lot of jargon I don't really understand. When I click on the "allow" button, it takes me to the url that I defined as my `redirect_uri`, and appended to the end of the string is the `state` that I set, as well as `code=` and then a string - so I assume I need to do something with those, but I don't know what.

I was wondering if there is a super simple "explain like I'm 5" step-by-step guide on what to do from here?

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard OAuth flow. [From the doc :](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2)

1. When the user clicks the "Sign on with Reddit" button on your website, you must redirect the user to the authorisation URL at Reddit - the one in your question, starting with `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize` and enriched with the request params you specified. Reddit will then ask the user to sign in, and whether or not he wants to authorise your app access to the requested scope. See https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#allowing-the-user-to-authorize-your-application
2. If the user agrees, then Reddit will redirect the user to the redirect URI you specified as request param in the authorisation URL (in your case, `http://localhost:8080/redditimageuploader/callback`). Reddit will add a `state` request param: you need to ensure that this is the same as the one in your request.
3. Retrieve the access token with a POST request to `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token`, including the following data in your data: `grant_type=authorization_code&code=CODE&redirect_uri=URI`. Replace CODE with the value you received and URI with your same redirect URI as in the first step.
   The response to this third step should return you an access token: store this for future requests on behalf of the user. See https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#retrieving-the-access-token

Extra steps are available and documented for error handling and access token operations (invalidation / renewal).

So, once you've correctly implemented the first step, all you need to do is create an endpoint (the one called when your redirect URI is redirected to) which will :

1. check the `state` request param
2. Retrieve the access token (third step) and store it

Let me know if this is clear enough.